# A basic relation in spherical coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems, vector-fields

Why is it that
$$x\partial_x+y\partial_y+z\partial_z=r\partial_r~?$$
I know that $$r^2=x^2+y^2+z^2,$$ but how is this relation implied?

Comment: Have you tried taking the differential of both sides? In any case this is a pure math question.

Comment: Hint: Chain rule.

Comment: Doesn't look like physics to me.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not talking about $rdr=xdx+ydy+zdz$. It's $$x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}=r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Cartesian coordinates,
$$
{\bf r} = x \ {\hat{\bf{ x}}} + y \ {\hat{\bf{ y}}} + z \ {\hat{\bf{ z}}}
$$
and
$$
\nabla = {\hat{\bf{ x}}} \ \partial_x + {\hat{\bf{ y}}} \ \partial_y + {\hat{\bf{ z}}} \ \partial_z
$$

In Spherical coordinates,
$$
{\bf r} = r \ {\hat{\bf{ r}}}
$$
and
$$
\nabla = {\hat{\bf{ r}}} \ \partial_r + {\hat{\bf{ \theta}}} \ \frac{1}{r} \partial_\theta + {\hat{\bf{ \phi}}} \ \frac{1}{r \sin \theta} \partial_\phi
$$

Now evaluate ${\bf r} \bullet \nabla$ in both coordinate systems.